# I wanna use Vertical Bar Chart using - npm install --save chart.js react-chartjs-2 but one error is coming?

Tags: reactjs, npm

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 7:0-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'faker' in '/home/badal/bargraph/src'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

My error is resolved using this command - npm i faker